# Can Jenkins run shell script on agent-less linux host

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, jenkins

I am looking for a Jenkins plugin that makes it execute simple shell script into a given machine.
A possible execution of this plugin would be:
Given hostname,username,password, execution folder, and script --> connect to the machine and execute the script.

Can I do it **without** pre-configuring the machine as Jenkins slave?

I've checked out **[ssh-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin)** and **[publish-over-ssh](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)** but they don't offer doing such thing without preconfiguring the hosts.

Comment: ssh-plugin is the one you want. Why is it not suitable for you ? There does not exist any way to execute shell scripts on a remote host without some form of server running, and an ssh server is normally running anyway.

Comment: alternatively just add a shell build step that runs on the server node and executes commands over ssh (you can use plink if you need to pass the credentials on command line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I couldn't find the right built-in solution for Jenkins but [Python Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) is an interesting direction